# Does broadcast recevier registered in Manifest file is called at the time of installation?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-manifest, manifest

I wanted to start application after reboot. I have installed the application and reboot the device it is not starting the application. It works only when I run the application one time after installation, if I restart the device it will start the application. Please let me know what are all the things getting called from the Manifest file at the time installation, what is the cause for this issue.

Thanks,

Comment: "Please let me know what are all the things getting called from the Manifest file at the time installation" what do you mean by this?

Comment: App icon,label,permissions,services,broadcast receivers. Components are there in the Manifest.My doubt is among these components which are all got executed at the time of installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please let me know what are all the things getting called from the Manifest file at the time installation

Nothing in your app is called at the point that the app is *installed*.

> It works only when I run the application one time after installation, if I restart the device it will start the application.

When installed, your app is in a so-called "stopped state". It will only become a normal app when something uses an explicit `Intent` to start one of your components. For the vast majority of apps, that "something" is the launcher, launching one of your `LAUNCHER` activities because the user clicked on it. While in the "stopped state", manifest-registered receivers will not work.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/broadcasts.html#manifest-declared-receivers),

> The system package manager registers the receiver when the app is installed. The receiver then becomes a separate entry point into your app which means that the system can start the app and deliver the broadcast if the app is not currently running.

As such, **to answer your question**, The BroadcastReceiver will be registered from  the Manifest file at the time of installation of your application.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. If we restart the device it will not work. Is it activated or not?. If it is not activated by Intent filter then how do we activate it, is there any way to do it.

Comment: Idk about that, there might be an issue with your code. If I may ask, what's the use case of Broadcast receivers for the app you are building?